# Java Swing: background of the whole ScrollBar (doesn't show up)

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar, styling

I am working on a swing app (let us omit why).

I need to make a custom design of a scrollbar. So far so good, I implemented my descendant of **ScrollBarUI** - i have custom buttons, custom thumb, custom track... except of the area around my buttons - I added some padding there and I want to wrap all my scrollbar into a rectangle with rounded corners.

As I haven't found means to do that in ScrollBarUI, I decided to extend **JScrollPane** (to extend **ScrollBar** which is used there, so I could draw my rounded rectangle in **paintComponent**). This is what I made:

```
public class MyScrollPane extends JScrollPane {
  public MyScrollPane(Component view) {
    super(view);
  }

  @Override
  public JScrollBar createVerticalScrollBar() {
    return new MyScrollBar(JScrollBar.VERTICAL);
  }

  @Override
  public JScrollBar createHorizontalScrollBar() {
    return new MyScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
  }

  protected class MyScrollBar extends ScrollBar {
    public MyScrollBar(int orientation) {
      super(orientation);
      setUI(MyScrollBarUI.createUI(this));
      setOpaque(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);

      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

      int borderDiameterX = 32;
      int borderDiameterY = 32;
  
      g2.translate(this.getX(), this.getY());
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.setColor(Color.gray);
      g2.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, borderDiameterX, borderDiameterY);
      g2.translate(-this.getX(), -this.getY());
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

- if `setOpacity(true)` - it draws squares of default color around buttons
- if `setOpacity(false)` - it doesn't draw background

Code is called, I checked. The inner elements of scrollbar - thumb, buttons are all fine.

[image: scrollbar, problem areas ugly circled]

What did I miss?

Comment: The [Nimbus look and feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html) has rounded scrollbars. Did you look at the code to see how they did it? As far as I am aware, you should only need to change the UI classes in order to change the look-and-feel.

Comment: @Abra No. Thank you, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. There were 3 issues in my code.

1. `setOpacity` must be `false` to prevent built-in background drawing.
2. `g2.translate` - not needed, mindlessly copied from ScrollBarUI code
3. `super.paintComponent(g)` - i moved it to the end of my paintComponent, otherwise drawing in MyScrollBarUI was behind my painted background.

So it looks like this now:

```
public class MyScrollPane extends JScrollPane {
  public MyScrollPane(Component view) {
    super(view);
  }

  @Override
  public JScrollBar createVerticalScrollBar() {
    return new MyScrollBar(JScrollBar.VERTICAL);
  }

  @Override
  public JScrollBar createHorizontalScrollBar() {
    return new MyScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
  }

  protected class MyScrollBar extends ScrollBar {
    public MyScrollBar(int orientation) {
      super(orientation);
      setUI(MyScrollBarUI.createUI(this));
      setOpaque(false);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

      int borderDiameter = 32;

      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.setColor(Color.gray);
      g2.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, borderDiameter, borderDiameter);

      super.paintComponent(g);
    }
  }
}
```